# Isomorphism between $k$-algebra and its localization at a nonzerodivisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> $k$ is a field. Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, $f$ a nonzerodivisor in $A$, and the localization $A_f\cong k[x,y]$ as $k$-algebras. Prove that $A\cong k[x,y]$.

This is my work:

Let $\phi$ be the isomorphism between $A_f$ and $k[x,y]$. Since $(1,f^n)$ is invertible in $A_f$, any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\phi((1,f^n))$ is also invertible in $k[x,y]$, hence $\phi((1,f^n))=k_n \in k$, then for any $(a,f^n) \in A_f$, $(a,f^n)=\phi^{-1}(\phi((a,f^n)))=\phi^{-1}(\phi((a,1))\phi((1,f^n)))=k_n(a,1)$.

Also, since $f$ is nonzerodivisor, the ring homomorphism $g: A \rightarrow A_f, a \mapsto (a,1)$ is injective.

So far it seems promising, but here comes my problem: next I want to show that the ring homomorphism $g$ is a $k$-algebra map, i.e., $g(\lambda a)\triangleq (\lambda a,1)=\lambda(a,1)$.

To be more specific, a $k$-algebra with unit is a ring with a injective homomorphism from $k$ to the ring. So we have triple $(k,A,\varphi)$ and $(k,A_f,\psi)$, let $\lambda \in k$ and $g:A\rightarrow A_f, a\mapsto (a,1)$, for $g$ to be a $k$-algebra map, we need to show the diagram $k\xrightarrow{\varphi}A\xrightarrow{g}A_f$ and $k\xrightarrow{\psi}A_f$ commutes, i.e., $g(\lambda a)\triangleq g(\varphi(\lambda)a)\triangleq(\varphi(\lambda) a,1)=\psi(\lambda)(a,1)\triangleq\lambda(a,1)$. And I don't see why the equality holds for any choice of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ that makes $A$ and $A_f$ $k$-algebras respectively.

Please help me with a proof as rigorous as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're making it slightly harder than it need be.

Here is a very rough sketch--you can fill in the formalism:

Let $\varphi:A_f\to k[x,y]$ be the isomorphism. Note then that $\varphi(f)\in k[x,y]^\times=k^\times$ and so since $\varphi$ is a $k$-algebra isomorphism, this implies that $f\in k^\times$ so that $f\in A^\times$. Thus, $A\cong A_f\cong k[x,y]$.

Comment: I'm a newbie in commutative algebra, so I really can't fill in the formalism, I would assume $f$ means $(f,1)$, but I don't even understand what you mean by $k[x,y]^\times$, let alone the implication afterwards. I would appreciate if you could explain it in a more basic and explicit manner, Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, technically I am identifying $f$ with $(f,1)$, and by $k[x,y]^\times$ I literally just mean the units of $k[x,y]$ which is just $k^\times$. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @user2690457 The map $A \to A_f$ is tautologically a $k$-algebra homomorphism, basically because of the way we define $k$ to act on $A_f$. More specifically, by a $k$-algebra $A$ we mean a triple $(k,A,\varphi)$, with $\varphi : k \to A$ an injective ring homomorphism. Using this $\varphi$, $A_f$ becomes a $k$-algebra with action of $k$ given by $x \cdot \frac{a}{f^n} = \frac{\varphi(x)}{1}\cdot \frac{a}{f^n}$ for any $x \in k$.

Comment: I tried but frustratedly I still can't work it through with hints from you guys.@AlexYoucis I still don't see why $f\in A^\times$ means $A \cong A_f$, what would be isomorphism map then? I tried $a \mapsto (a,1)$ but still stuck at how to show it's k-algebra map.@Benja Follow your notation, for triple$(k,A,\varphi)$ and $(k,A_f,\phi)$, I think to show $a \mapsto (a,1)$ is $k$-algebra map, if $x \in k$, we need to show $(xa,1)\triangleq(\varphi(x)a,1)=(\varphi(x),1)(a,1)=\phi(x)(a,1)\triangleq x(a,1)$, but I still don't know why the equality holds.

Comment: @user2690457 Think about it like this. The localization of $A$ at $\{1,f,f^2,\ldots\}$ is the following data: a ring $R$ and a homomorphism $s:A\to R$ which satisfies the following property: if $B$ is any ring and $g:A\to B$ is any ring homomorphism such that $g(f)\in B^\times$ then there exists a unique ring homomorphism $t:R\to B$ such that $g=t\circ s$. It's not hard to show that if $s:A\to R$ and $s':A\to R'$ are two different localizations that $R\cong R'$. Now, you have given one construction of $s:A\to R$. Namely, you have defined $A_f$ to be formal quotients (pairs) that satisfy

Comment: yada yada. The map $A\to A_f$ in the definition I mentioned above is just $a\mapsto (a,1)$. So, now try showing that since $f\in k^\times$ that the identity map $\text{id}:A\to A$ actually defines a localization of $A$ at $\{1,f,f^2,\ldots\}$. Thus, you see that $A\cong A_f$.

Comment: @user2690457 Informally, $A_f$ is the ring that one gets by forcing $f$ to be invertible--if $f$ is already invertible, you don't get a new ring.

Comment: I'm appreciate that you've written so much, but after some work I'm still stuck at the problem that the map $a \mapsto (a,1)$ satisfies the $k$-algebra map property, if you don't think it's a waste of your time, would you please tell me why it is true?

Comment: @user2690457 The reason why it's a $k$-algebra map is by definition. How would you define $\lambda(a,b)$, you'd define it by $(\lambda a,b)$. This says precisely that the map $a\mapsto (a,1)$ is a $k$-algebra map.

Comment: I wish I could define it this way, but this is the very question I'm asking. Because both λa and λ(a,1) has their own definition as k-algebra. To be more specific, a k-algebra with unit is a ring with a injective homomorphism from k to the ring. So we have triple (k,A,φ) and (k,Af,ϕ), let λ∈k and g:A→Af,a↦(a,1), for g to be a k-algebra map, we need to show the diagram k→φA→gAf and k→ϕAfcommutes, i.e.,g(λa)≜g(φ(λ)a)≜(φ(λ)a,1)=ϕ(λ)(a,1)≜λ(a,1). And I don't see why the equality holds for any choice of φ and ϕ that makes A and Af k-algebra respetively.